# push array's value to object's value

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, object

I have a question about the array and object conversion. I have an array which has three values. if my object has already had its key, how do I put the array value to the object by for loop?

If I use for loop like below, every value is engineer.

```
let arr= ['john', 29, 'engineer']
let obj = {}
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    obj.name = arr[i]
    obj.age = arr[i]
    obj.job = arr[i]
}

console.log(obj)
```

The result of above code:

```
{
  name: 'engineer',
  age: 'engineer',
  job: 'engineer'
}
```

Instead, I want the following result:

```
{
  name: 'john',
  age: 29,
  job: 'engineer'
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use array destructuring.

```js
let arr = ['john', 29, 'engineer'];
const [name, age, job] = arr;
let obj = {name,age,job};
console.log(obj);
```

You can refer to the indexes using bracket notation as well, if all the values will always be at the same position.

```js
let arr= ['john', 29, 'engineer']
let obj = {
    name: arr[0],
    age: arr[1],
    job: arr[2]
};

console.log(obj);
```